# How to start with Augmented reality to create my own framework (Not AR App)

Tags: augmented-reality

I have been working Augmented Reality for quite a few months. I have used third party tools like Unity/Vuforia to create augmented reality applications for android.

I would like to create my own framework in which I will create my own AR apps. Can someone guide me to right tutorials/links to achieve my target. On a higher level, my plan is to create an application which can recognize multiple markers and match it with cloud stored models.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a massive undertaking:  model recognition is not an easy task.  I recommend looking at OpenCV (which has some standard algorithms you can use as a starting point) and then looking at a good computer vision book (e.g., [Richard Szeliski's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BMTJ482) or [Hartley and Zisserman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521540518)).

But you are going to run into a host of practical problems.  Consider that systems like Vuforia provide camera calibration data for most Android devices, and it's hard to do computer vision without it.  Then, of course, there's efficiently managing the whole pipeline which (again) companies like Qualcomm and Metaio invest huge amounts of $$ in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a project that does framemarker tracking and I've started exporting bits of it out to a project I'm calling [OpenAR](https://github.com/palmerc/OpenAR). Right now I'm in the process of pulling out unpublishable pieces and making Vuforia and the OpenCV versions of marker tracking interchangeable. You're certainly welcome to check out the work as it progresses. You can see videos of some of the early work on [my YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwb4BXRCppjigB410n8M91g?spfreload=10).

The hard work is improving performance to be as good as Vuforia.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely check it out